# Why is the product operator of $\sigma$-algebras associative?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_i,\mathcal{A}_i)$, $i=1,\cdots,n$, be mesurable spaces.
Why does it holds that
$$\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{A}_i=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{A}_i \ \otimes \mathcal{A_n} $$
or in general

$$\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{A}_i=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{m}\mathcal{A}_i \otimes  \bigotimes_{i=m+1}^{n} \mathcal{A_i} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing weird, you can easily see the $\sigma$ algebra of $\Omega_i\times\Omega_j$ is indeed $\mathcal{A}_{i}\bigotimes\mathcal{A}_{j}$ and the rest follows by induction.